# SQLite dropping rows from result of select

Tags: sql, sqlite

For example I execute `SELECT` query which result is set of rows `R`. Is any way to drop from `R` rows that satisfied condition which depends on last row of `R`? Before executing `SELECT` query the condition is unknown. I thought about some `PROCEDURE` but i can't write it :(. Anyone can help? :).

Answer (score 1):

Insert your query into a temp table:
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

then select again from your table based on the last_insert_rowid of the temp table:
https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid